# How can I have check constraint in django which check two fields of related models?

Tags: django, django-models

```
from django.db import models
from djago.db.models import F, Q

class(models.Model):
    order_date = models.DateField()
    
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKeyField(Order)
    loading_date = models.DateField()
    
    class Meta:

        constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(check=Q(loading_date__gte=F("order__order_date")), name="disallow_backdated_loading")
```

I want to make sure always orderline loading_date is higher than orderdate

Comment: You don't. Normally such database constraints are limited to a single table, it can not "follow" foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Most databases support something like a trigger where you can indeed write code to reject the change, but currently Django does not implement such triggers. You can run "raw SQL" to implement such trigger, although these do *not* work on all database variants.

Comment: There is on databases an *ugly* trick to let this work with a composite primary key, but Django does not allow composite primary keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `CHECK` constraint can span over a column, or over a *table*, but not over *multiple* tables, so this is not possible through a `CHECK` constraint.

Some databases allow to define triggers. These triggers run for example when a records is created/updated, and can run SQL queries, and decide to reject the creation/update based on such queries, but currently, the Django ORM does not support that.

One could also work with a composite primary key of an id and the creation date of the order, in which case the create timestamp is thus stored in the `OrderLine` table, and thus one can implement a check at the table level, but Django does not support working with composite primary keys for a number of reasons.

Therefore, besides running raw SQL, for example with a migration file that has a [**`RunSQL`** operation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runsql), but this will likely be specific towards a database.

Therefore probably the most sensical check is to override the model [**`clean()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean). Django however does *not* run the `.clean()` method before saving an object in the database, this is only done by `ModelForm`s, and `ModelAdmin`s. We can thus add a check with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKeyField(
        Order,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    loading_date = models.DateField()
    
    def clean(self):
        if self.loading_date < self.order.order_date:
            raise ValidationError('Can not load before ordering')
        return super().clean()
```